# How to install package using pip when you have 2 Python versions

Tags: python

I have `2` anaconda in my system: `one with python 2.7` & and `another with python 3.5`.

My command prompt is showing python version as `2.7`.

I need to install one package for `Python 3.5` using `pip` only,not conda install. I installed it using pip. It's showing installed successfully, but **I'm not able to import it in Anaconda with Python 3.5**.

My python 2.7 path is given in path environmental variable. Can you suggest me how to install it using pip install for `python 3.5`?
I don't have python 3 installed in my system. I think I have anaconda 3.5 environment in my system. Please refer the screen shot. Also I can't able to install python 3.5 in my system
[image]

Comment: did you try `python3` in your command line?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It's showing python3 is not recognized as internal or external command

Answer (score 2):

To install a package in specific version, try this:

#### A specific version of python:

```
$ python-3.5 -m pip install <pkg-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that you have two `conda` environments, go to a Anaconda command prompt and activate the Python 3.5 environment. Then, if `pip` is not installed, do:

```
conda install pip
```

Then, you should be able to run

```
pip install <package>
```

to install in to Python 3.5 provided that you are in the Python 3.5 environment.

If you don't have a Python 3.5 environment yet, simply do

```
conda create --name py35 python=3.5
```

followed by

```
activate py35          (Windows)
source activate py35   (Linux or macOS)
```

Comment: This should be the answer for a system with Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PATH_PREFIX" <package_name>
```

or

```
pip install -t <direct directory> <package_name>
```

Comment: Actually I don't have python 3.5 in my system. I think I have anaconda 3.5 environment in my system. Please refer the screen shot, I have updated in my original post & also I can't able to install python 3.5 in my system